# Pass data between fragment viewmodels

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

Let me just say up front that this is more of a "structural" question, and I'm not asking anybody to write code; I'm just trying to figure out how I should be structuring my application.

I'm using Android's `DrawerLayout`/`NavigationView` for my app. This means that `MainActivity` is the host for all my fragments.

I currently have three fragments (in reality it's many more, but they are more or less exactly like these three fragments, just for different sets of data).

- ListFragment
- DetailFragment
- EditFragment (used for both adding and editing)

On my `ListFragment` I have (surprise!) a list of items. This is a `LiveData` collection on `SharedViewModel` (which is tied to `MainActivity`'s lifecycle). When an item is tapped I pass the event through to `MainActivity` by means of an interface listener.

`MainActivity` then loads up the `DetailFragment`. In the same call, I load an instance of `SharedViewModel` (again tied to `MainActivity`). I set `SharedViewModel.selectedItem` to be the tapped item. Then, in `DetailFragment`'s `onCreate` function, I get the selected item via `ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java).selectedItem`.

On the `DetailFragment`, there's an edit button. This goes through more or less the same routine described above, but loading up the `EditFragment` instead. When the edited/added item is saved, I add/replace the item in `SharedViewModel`'s collection through `MainActivity`'s interface listener.

Obviously this is not optimal for several reasons. For one, it means that I've got at least five large sets of data hanging around for `MainActivity`'s lifecycle (the entire lifecycle of the app, essentially). Also, `MainActivity` grows way out of hand as I have to add more and more functions to handle events.

What I *want* to do is have, for example, my list of items on a `ListFragmentViewModel` which is tied to *`ListFragment`'s lifecycle*.  My selected item on a `DetailFragmentViewModel`, my editing item on an `EditFragmentViewModel`, etc.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to properly pass the data around in this case. For example, let's say I add a new item in `EditFragment`. How do I get that into `ListFragmentViewModel`'s collection of items? `ListFragment` is in the back-stack, so its viewmodel hangs around and doesn't reload the data when it's navigated back to, since it still has the collection from before. This makes sense and is probably how it *should* be (after all, who wants to wait for all the data to load when they go to `DetailFragment` and back to `ListFragment`?), but it means that I don't get my new item in the collection.

That's just one example, but I'm running into quite a few issues like it (e.g. passing the selected item to `DetailFragmentViewModel`.)

I'm not quite sure what direction I should even be going here. Can someone more experienced help me out?

Comment: Theoretically the Activity ViewModel is the shared superscoped view model that can share the data to all fragments via LiveData subscription.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That's what I'm currently doing, but it means that I've got potentially _thousands_ of items there that aren't even being used anymore. That seems really bad.

Comment: Paging library will solve this problem, but it's currently `alpha5`

Comment: When dealing with large datasets it is common to use some type of persistent store and then pass the id of the item that is of interest to the next object. That object will then access the repository(persistent store) and retrieve the details for that id.

Comment: @dazza5000 I'd considered doing that. However, it means 1) more network requests for the user and 2) more network requests (i.e. higher charges) for my API. Also I could be wrong, but I don't think that quite takes care of the issue of what to do when an item is changed or added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> let's say I add a new item in EditFragment. How do I get that into ListFragmentViewModel's collection of items?

`EditFragment` tells your item repository, "yo! here's a new item!". The item repository arranges to update your backing store, plus emits an event to interested parties notifying about the data change (e.g., emits an event on an RxJava `PublishSubject`). The `ListFragmentViewModel` listens for those events and reacts accordingly.

> ListFragment is in the back-stack, so its viewmodel hangs around and doesn't reload the data when it's navigated back to, since it still has the collection from before

It should be finding out about the data change from your item repository, and doing whatever makes sense to reflect that data change. That could be simply taking data from the data-change event and updating its in-memory content. That could be re-requesting information from the backing store. In principle, it could be something else.

Comment: I'll look into RxJava. It sounds like that could be the answer to my problems. Either way you've definitely given me useful information here. If you happen to know off the top of your head, would `ListFragmentViewModel` still receive events even though it's not attached to the currently active fragment?

Comment: @RareNCool: Assuming that you are referring to the official `ViewModel` implementation from the Architecture Components, I think it should be OK. It dawns on me as I write this that the scenarios where I have used the pattern in my answer, it was with an activity-level `ViewModel`, not a fragment-level one. However, either your `ListFragmentViewModel` will still exist in the provider's cache (in which case, it can remain subscribed to the event stream), or the `ListFragmentViewModel` gets recreated from scratch (in which case, you don't have the out-of-date data anyway, as that's gone).

Comment: So the item repository should be a singleton and hold the state? Is it Ok for the repository to be a singleton?

Comment: @Angelina: Repositories, where used, are almost always singletons. However, ideally, they are managed by a dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.) rather than being ordinary `static` Java fields, Kotlin `object`, etc. That way, the consumers of the repositories can use mocks or fakes in testing. The repository itself then often delegates to "data store" objects for saving things to files, databases, the Web service, etc. The repository handles details of converting between models used by the main app and the objects needed by those data stores (e.g., Room entities, Retrofit types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you suggest to use DI scope for repository and it is OK? I was worried about keeping a state in a singleton. Because if a repo is used to share data between 2 ViewModels it has to be singleton, i guess.

Comment: @Angelina: "So you suggest to use DI scope for repository and it is OK?" -- that is a typical solution. "Because if a repo is used to share data between 2 ViewModels it has to be singleton, i guess." -- correct.